# Problems while merging many text files side by side using paste

Tags: text-processing

I have to merge hundreds of .txt files side by side. I've been trying to use some of the already answered questions in the forums but while the files do merge, the second, and third (so on) files shift one line down every time. I would like for them to stay aligned, all of the files have the same number of rows (if not characters in each row). My files are separated by commas, and my ultimate goal is to get them all to excel for data processing.

my files are

591.txt

```
CT Analyser, Version: 1.9.3.2 
Date and time,25.07.2014 09:56 
Operator identity,svy557 
Computer name,UT156805 
Computation time,00:08:24
Dataset,591_right__rec_tra_voi 
Location,D:\Pam Mandible Copy\591\Right\Region1\
```

583.txt

```
CT Analyser, Version: 1.9.3.2
Date and time,31.07.2014 15:14
Operator identity,svy557
Computer name,UT156805
Computation time,00:10:04
Dataset,583_left__rec_tra
Location,D:\Pam Mandible Copy\583 Left\Reoriented\
```

I have tried something like the following:

```
paste 591.txt 593.txt | column -s $'\t' -t
```

it merges like this (the second file one line below, instead of lines next to each other):

```
CT Analyser, Version: 1.9.3.2
                     CT Analyser, Version: 1.9.3.2
Date and time,25.07.2014 09:56
                    Date and time,25.07.2014 09:55
Operator identity,svy557
                          Operator identity,svy557
Computer name,UT156805
                            Computer name,UT156805
Computation time,00:08:24
                         Computation time,00:08:13
Dataset,591_right__rec_tra_voi
                    Dataset,583_right__rec_tra_voi
Location,D:\Pam Mandible Copy\591 Right\Region1\
  Location,D:\Pam Mandible Copy\583 Right\Region1\
```

This is been driving crazy for a few days and any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm pretty new with UNIX so I'm trying to learn enough to do this and then other few project that require similar skills. The actual files have about 50 rows and all of them look like that, if I try to do more than one file with something like this:

```
paste -d '\n' *.txt > new.txt
```

The results become unpredictable

```
 CT Analyser, Version: 1.9.3.2
CT Analyser, Version: 1.9.3.2
CT Analyser, Version: 1.9.3.2
CT Analyser, Version: 1.9.3.2
CT Analyser, Version: 1.9.3.2
                     CT Analyser, Version: 1.9.3.2

Date and time,25.07.2014 09:55
Date and time,25.07.2014 09:55
Date and time,25.07.2014 09:56
Date and time,25.07.2014 09:56
Date and time,25.07.2014 09:56
                    Date and time,25.07.2014 09:55

Operator identity,svy557
Operator identity,svy557
Operator identity,svy557
Operator identity,svy557
Operator identity,svy557
                          Operator identity,svy557

Computer name,UT156805
Computer name,UT156805
Computer name,UT156805
Computer name,UT156805
Computer name,UT156805
                            Computer name,UT156805

Computation time,00:08:13
Computation time,00:08:13
Computation time,00:08:24
Computation time,00:08:24
Computation time,00:08:24
                         Computation time,00:08:13

Dataset,583_right__rec_tra_voi
Dataset,583_right__rec_tra_voi
Dataset,591_right__rec_tra_voi
Dataset,591_right__rec_tra_voi
Dataset,591_right__rec_tra_voi
                    Dataset,583_right__rec_tra_voi

Location,D:\Pam Mandible Copy\583 Right\Region1\
Location,D:\Pam Mandible Copy\583 Right\Region1\
Location,D:\Pam Mandible Copy\591 Right\Region1\
Location,D:\Pam Mandible Copy\591 Right\Region1\
Location,D:\Pam Mandible Copy\591 Right\Region1\
  Location,D:\Pam Mandible Copy\583 Right\Region1\
```

Thanks again for all the help

Comment: Why don't you just do `paste *.txt`?

Comment: Thanks, but that only staggers them, I would like them to be side by side.

Comment: If you use `paste *.txt` it's next to each other for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that there are trailing spaces on these lines, and that's pushing it into wraparound. Have you tried dumping the start of a file in octal/hex to see if that's the case?

You could then use a simple `sed` command to fix all the files in a looping shell script before you started.

Answer (score 0):

What is probably the case here is that the original files contain windows linebreaks. The command `paste` seems to go wrong with windows linebreaks in combination with the delimiter. You can check this by using `od` on the files. If it contains `\r\n`, you first need to fix this. Fixing this can be done with `dos2unix`.

A check on my system:

```
[stc@se] $ echo -e "foo\r" > a ; echo -e "bar\r" > b
[stc@se] $ od -c a
0000000   f   o   o  \r  \n
0000005
[stc@se] $ paste a b
foo     bar
[stc@se] $ paste -d"," a b
,bar
```

Fixing this with `dos2unix`:

```
[stc@se] $ dos2unix a b
dos2unix: converting file a to Unix format...
dos2unix: converting file b to Unix format...
[stc@se] $ paste -d"," a b
foo,bar
```

`dos2unix` is not installed by default on all linux systems, so you might still need to install that.